# Get the content of returned multimap iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, pass-by-reference, multimap

I am returning multimap iterator from called function.

code:

```
std::multimap<int,std::string>::iterator it = dst.begin();

     for(int count = 0;count<3 && it !=dst.end();++it,++count)
       std::cout<<it->second<<":"<<it->first<<std::endl;

     return it;
```

And calling function:

```
std::multimap<int,std::string>::const_iterator rec;
    rec= client(); 

    for(int count = 0;count<3 ;++count)
       std::cout<<rec->second<<":"<<rec->first<<std::endl; // Prints garbage values
```

Here Why I could not print content of `rec` directly? In called function `std::cout<<it->second<<":"<<it->first<<std::endl;` prints correct value!

Entire code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<map>
#include<vector>

std::multimap<int,std::string>::iterator client()  
{

    std::vector<std::string> most { "lion","tiger","kangaroo",
                                     "donkey","lion","tiger",
                                     "lion","donkey","tiger"
                                     };
    std::map<std::string, int> src;
    for(auto x:most)
        ++src[x];

    std::multimap<int,std::string,std::greater<int> > dst;

    std::transform(src.begin(), src.end(), std::inserter(dst, dst.begin()), 
                       [] (const std::pair<std::string,int> &p) {
                       return std::pair<int,std::string>(p.second, p.first);
                       }
                     );

    std::multimap<int,std::string>::iterator it = dst.begin();

    for(int count = 0;count<3 && it !=dst.end();++it,++count)
        std::cout<<it->second<<":"<<it->first<<std::endl;

    return it;  
}

int main()
{

    std::multimap<int,std::string>::const_iterator rec;
    rec= client(); 

    for(int count = 0;count<3 ;++count,++rec)
    std::cout<<rec->second<<":"<<rec->first<<std::endl;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot return iterator to local object, it becomes invalid when you return from function and local object `multimap dst` is destroyed. You need another design, maybe create object on the free store (return sharedpointer?) or make it static, or pass by reference like this:

```
std::multimap<int,std::string>::iterator 
          client(std::multimap<int,std::string,std::greater<int> >& dst) {

    std::vector<std::string> most { "lion","tiger","kangaroo",
                                     "donkey","lion","tiger",
                                     "lion","donkey","tiger"
                                     };
    std::map<std::string, int> src;
    for(auto x:most)
        ++src[x];

    std::transform(src.begin(), src.end(), std::inserter(dst, dst.begin()), 
                       [] (const std::pair<std::string,int> &p) {
                       return std::pair<int,std::string>(p.second, p.first);
                       }
                     );

    std::multimap<int,std::string>::iterator it = dst.begin();

     for(int count = 0;count<3 && it !=dst.end();++it,++count)
       std::cout<<it->second<<":"<<it->first<<std::endl;

     return dst.begin();  
    }
```

usage:

```
int main(){
    std::multimap<int,std::string,std::greater<int> > dst;
    std::multimap<int,std::string>::const_iterator rec;
    rec = client(dst);

    for(int count = 0;count<3 ;++count,++rec)
       std::cout<<rec->second<<":"<<rec->first<<std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

Note:
also return `dst.begin()` not `it`, because otherwise you might face undefined behavior: it might point out of range because it was incremented before return in `client()`.

Comment: thanks a lot. One more question if you can solve: `for(int count = 0;count<3 && it !=dst.end();++it,++count)
       std::cout<<it->second<<":"<<it->first<<std::endl;` prints first 3 most occurring words. I want to print all three most occurring word. Can you please give some guide!

Comment: Not relavant to main question. But grateful if you can answer!

Comment: sorry; "prints first 3 most occurring words. I want to print all three most occurring word" all three, or all in the multimap?

Comment: just print all, delete count<3 and print while it!=dst.end()

Comment: btw: the name client for this function is quite strange

Comment: yes. Actually above code is snippet of my original code. Which words as client for my application!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36623/discussion-between-karimkhan-and-computer)

Answer (score 1):

The lifetime of the object `dst` ends when you return from the function `client`. At that point, iterators obtained from the map become *invalid*, and it is undefined behaviour to dereference them.

Comment: Solution? I define `std::multimap<int,std::string,std::greater<int> > dst;` then it gives segmentation fault in `main`

Comment: Solution for *what*? Redesign your program? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: No, no redesign. Please just correct me where I am wrong. I am facing problem in printing `rec` returned from `client()` function. That what I want to do.

Comment: You're wrong to do something that makes no sense. You can't return an iterator to a container that doesn't exist. Do something else instead, e.g. return the elements directly by value, or store them in a pre-supplied container, or return a new container.

Answer (score 1):

An iterator is essentially a pointer, and you're returning an iterator to a local variable that will expire at the end of the `client` call. That's why you're getting garbage values.

Comment: Solution? I defined `std::multimap<int,std::string,std::greater<int> > dst;` then it gives segmentation fault in main

Comment: Make `dst` `static` (assuming it's a local variable)